# Compacity of the space non increasing sequences on $[0,C]$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

So let S denote the space of non increasing sequences valued In $[0,C]$. I have to prove S is compact given the usual sequence metric ( $d(x,y) = \sum_{i=0} \frac {|x_i - y_i|}{2^i}$ ).

My primary idea was to use a diagonal argument to build a convergent subsequence but it felt rather unsatisfying proving it this way. I also tried to build the subsequence myself but couldnt so far. Any hints about building the subsequence or any other method would be welcomed.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space of sequences in $[0,C]$ under the product topology is $[0,C]^\mathbb{N}$, which is compact by Tychonoff. It is well known and easy to show that it is metrizable, with the metric you gave. Let $X \subseteq [0,C]^\mathbb{N}$ be the subset consisting of non-decreasing sequences. The fact that $X$ is compact will follow from showing it is closed in $[0,C]^\mathbb{N}$.

But this is easy. Take a sequence $(x_n)_n \in X$ and suppose $x_n \to x \in [0,C]^\mathbb{N}$. Then, if $x = (y_1,y_2,\dots)$, the fact that $y_{k+1} \le y_k$ follows from the fact that this holds for each $x_n$ and the fact that the topology is pointwise convergence.